# How can I save a CNTK model as text?

Tags: cntk

I have a neural network created and trained in CNTK. I can save it with model.save_model("mymodel.dnn") in Python. This produces a file serialized in protobuf format.
How can I either save the model as plain text or convert the .dnn file to plain text?

Answer (score 3):

The format CNTK uses is protobuf. Therefore you can use things like

`import google.protobuf.text_format`

to create a readable output. [This page](https://interania.com/t5/Getting-Started/Converting-Protocol-Buffers-ProtoBuf-to-JSON-for-ingestion/td-p/345) has further information.

Our protobuf files are currently in [this location](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/v2.0.beta9.0/Source/CNTKv2LibraryDll/proto). I'm hard linking to version 2b9. Make sure you use the right `.proto` file.

Answer (score 2):

The protobuf compiler can generate textual representation from a binary model file, you just need to point to the CNTK proto definition and tell it to expect a Dictionary inside the model file:

```
%PROTOBUF_PATH%\bin\protoc --decode CNTK.proto.Dictionary --proto_path [CNTK root]\Source\CNTKv2LibraryDll\proto\ [CNTK root]\Source\CNTKv2LibraryDll\proto\CNTK.proto < mymodel.dnn >  mymodel.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With Brainscript you can add

```
command = <yourCommands>:DumpNodeInfo
modelDir = "./ANNmodel"
modelPath = "$modelDir$/NN.dnn"

...

# dump parameter values
DumpNodeInfo = {
    action = "dumpNode"
    printValues = true
}
```

Click [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Tutorial#command-dumpnodeinfo) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the model trained by CNTK to txt format with CNTK's dumpnode command. Here is contents config file txt.conf:

```
command = convert2txt

convert2txt = [
    action = "dumpnode"    
    modelPath="./cntkSpeechFF.dnn.5"
    nodeName = "Prior" # if not specified, all nodes will be printed
    outputFile = "./cntkSpeechFF.dnn.5.txt" # the path to the output file. If not specified a file name will be automatically generated based on the modelPath.

    printValues = true
    printMetadata = true

]
```

Then you run cntk as

```
cntk configFile=txt.conf
```